# How to create a demo for the website as clickable html pages?

Tags: web, demo

We have to create the demo for our web application.Our application is a J2EE app.We have to demo some of the functionality as clickable HTMls.Is there a way we can do that using some tool instead of doing it manually, we donot want to use products for flash demo's etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a web spider or similar to dump the raw HTML output.  Personally I would try the [ScrapBook](http://amb.vis.ne.jp/mozilla/scrapbook/) Firefox plugin, but I'm sure there are many others.

Comment: Thats exactly what i wanted,i just used scrapbook its pretty good.